# how to print the below pattern

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

for the given input I need to print the pattern. For example for input = 6 I have to print:

```
MMMMMMSDDDDDD
MMMMMSSSDDDDD
MMMMSSSSSDDDD
MMMSSSSSSSDDD
MMSSSSSSSSSDD
MSSSSSSSSSSSD
CSSSSSSSSSSSK
CCSSSSSSSSSKK
CCCSSSSSSSKKK
CCCCSSSSSKKKK
CCCCCSSSKKKKK
CCCCCCSKKKKKK
```

I have tried but couldn't go further than this could anyone help

```
public class tgk {

public static void main(String[] args)  {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int size = sc.nextInt();

    int half = ((2*size)+1)/2;
     for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) 
     { 
         for (int j = size; j > i; j--) 
         {
         System.out.print("M");
          }
     for (int k = half+1 ; k > half - i; k--) 
     {
         System.out.print("S");
     }






    System.out.println();
 }


     for(int i = size; i > 0; i--)
     {
         for (int j = size; j >= i; j--) {
             System.out.print("C");
         }
         for (int k = 0; k < (i * 2 - 1); k++) {
             System.out.print("S");
         }



         System.out.println();
     }
}

}
```

if input = 3 it should be

```
MMMSDDD
MMSSSDD
MSSSSSD
CSSSSSK
CCSSSKK
CCCSKKK
```

Comment: I am not exactly sure what 6 has got to do with the pattern you wish to be printed. Maybe you can clarify that.

Comment: Is this description accurate:

You need to output a rectangle that is (input+1 x input) with a diamond of 'S's.  Corners are triangles that fit within (input x input) and filled with 'M's, 'D's, 'C's, 'K's clockwise from top-left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two sets of `for` loops to print each half of the pattern. Assuming `input` variable holds the size of the problem

```
int input = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < input; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < input - i; j++) {
        System.out.print('M');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print('S');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < input - i; j++) {
        System.out.print('D');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
for (int i = input - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < input - i; j++) {
        System.out.print('C');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) {
        System.out.print('S');
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < input - i; j++) {
        System.out.print('K');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

will print for `input = 3`:

```
MMMSDDD
MMSSSDD
MSSSSSD
CSSSSSK
CCSSSKK
CCCSKKK
```

and for `input = 6`:

```
MMMMMMSDDDDDD
MMMMMSSSDDDDD
MMMMSSSSSDDDD
MMMSSSSSSSDDD
MMSSSSSSSSSDD
MSSSSSSSSSSSD
CSSSSSSSSSSSK
CCSSSSSSSSSKK
CCCSSSSSSSKKK
CCCCSSSSSKKKK
CCCCCSSSKKKKK
CCCCCCSKKKKKK
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but I really wanted it to work with only one set of for-loops:

```
    int number = 8;

    for (int i = 0; i < number * 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (number * 2) + 1; j++) {
            System.out.print(
                i <  number && j+i < number ?    'M' :
                i <  number && j-i > number ?    'D' :
                i <  number                 ?    'S' :
                i >= number && i-j >= number ?   'C' :
                i >= number && j+i >= number*3 ? 'K' :
                                                 'S'
            );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

So for `8` (like in the code) it prints:

```
MMMMMMMMSDDDDDDDD
MMMMMMMSSSDDDDDDD
MMMMMMSSSSSDDDDDD
MMMMMSSSSSSSDDDDD
MMMMSSSSSSSSSDDDD
MMMSSSSSSSSSSSDDD
MMSSSSSSSSSSSSSDD
MSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSD
CSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSK
CCSSSSSSSSSSSSSKK
CCCSSSSSSSSSSSKKK
CCCCSSSSSSSSSKKKK
CCCCCSSSSSSSKKKKK
CCCCCCSSSSSKKKKKK
CCCCCCCSSSKKKKKKK
CCCCCCCCSKKKKKKKK
```

...or for `3`:

```
MMMSDDD
MMSSSDD
MSSSSSD
CSSSSSK
CCSSSKK
CCCSKKK
```